# Centers and Onto Group Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

If $G$ and $H$ are groups and $f: G \to H$ is a surjective homomorphism, I can clearly see that $f(Z(G))\subseteq Z(H)$. However, I am unable to find examples where this subset relation is proper, i.e., $f(Z(G))\subsetneq Z(H)$.

The reason I am looking for such an example is because I want to prove that if $G$ is nilpotent and $f: G \to H$ is a surjective homomorphism then $H$ is nilpotent. I am using Dummit Foote to study this topic and the authors define a group to be nilpotent if its [upper central series](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Upper_central_series) eventually becomes the entire group. If I could prove that the upper central series $Z_i (G)$ and $Z_i(H)$ satisfy that $f(Z_i(G))=Z_i(H)$ for each $i\in \mathbb Z _{\ge 0}$ then I will be done. However the case $i=1$ may not hold and this claim is apparently doomed.

**I would appreciate if someone points me in the right direction to find a example of (nilpotent) groups $G$ and $H$ and a surjective group homomorphism $f:G\to H$ such that $f(Z(G))\subsetneq Z(H)$.**

Comment: $S_3$ has trivial center and surjects onto $C_2$. That's the smallest example where the image of the center is properly contained in the center of the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $A_5$, a simple non-abelian group. Consider $G=A_5\wr C_2$,  the  wreath product with the cyclic group of order $2$. Then the center of $G$ is trivial, but there is a surjective homomorphism $G\to C_2$ and the center of $C_2$ is $C_2$.

About nilpotent example, take $G=C_2\wr Q_8$, the wreath product of $C_2$ and the quaternion group. It is a 2-group, hence nilpotent. The center of it is inside $C_2^8$. Consider the natural homomorphism $G\to Q_8$, the image of the center of $G$ is trivial, but the center of $Q_8$ is not trivial.

Comment: Thank you! But I am not familiar with wreath products. I may have to look it up. Is there any other construction that can be done to come up with such an example?

Comment: I do not know what constructions you are familiar with.

Comment: I am familiar with Direct Products and Semidirect Products.

Comment: The generalized quaternion group $Q_{16}$ has a center $Z\cong C_2$, but $Q_{16}/Z\cong Q_8$, so $Q_{16}$ is another counterexample.  Also, simply, $Q_8$ has center of order 2, but $Q_8/Z\cong C_2\times C_2$, a counterexample.

Comment: The wreath product is a semidirect product,

Answer (score 1):

Consider $G = S_3$, say (or any $S_n$ with $n \geq 3$). The center is trivial, so if you can find a non-trivial Abelian group H and a surjective homomorphism $f: S_3 \to H$, then you're done. There's a very well-known example of such a homomorphism that you've probably seen if you've studied symmetric groups.